# Не работает перегрузка оператора <<

Tags: c++

В чем может ошибка быть?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class NOTE
{
private:
    string name;//Имя Фамилия
    string phone;//Номер телефона
    string birthday;//Дата рождения
public:
    NOTE();//Конструктор по умолчанию
    NOTE(string n, string p, string b);//Конструктор 
    string GetName();//Получение значения имени
    string GetPhone();//Получение значения номера телефона
    string GetBirthday();//Получение значения дня рождения
    void SetName(string n);//Установка Имени
    void SetPhone(string p);//Установка номера телефона
    void SetBirthday(string b);//Установка Дня Рождения
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out);
};
#include "Note.h"
#include <iostream>
NOTE::NOTE()//Конструктор по умолчанию, устанавливающий все значения = 0
{
    name = "0";
    phone = "0";
    birthday = "0";
}
NOTE::NOTE(string n, string p, string b)//Конструктор с 3-мя передаваемыми значениями
{
    name = n;
    phone = p;
    birthday = b;
}
string NOTE::GetName()//Функция для отображения имени
{
    return name;
}
string NOTE::GetPhone()//Функция для отображения телефона
{
    return phone;
}
string NOTE::GetBirthday()//Функция для отображения дня рождения
{
    return birthday;
}
void NOTE::SetName(string n)//Функция для установки имени
{
    name = n;
}
void NOTE::SetPhone(string p)//Функция для установки телефона
{
    phone=p;
}
void NOTE::SetBirthday(string b)//Функция для установки дня рождения
{
    birthday=b;
}
std::ostream& NOTE:: operator<< (std::ostream& out)
{
    out << name;
    return out;
}


#include "Note.h"
#include <iostream>
NOTE::NOTE()//Конструктор по умолчанию, устанавливающий все значения = 0
{
    name = "0";
    phone = "0";
    birthday = "0";
}
NOTE::NOTE(string n, string p, string b)//Конструктор с 3-мя передаваемыми значениями
{
    name = n;
    phone = p;
    birthday = b;
}
string NOTE::GetName()//Функция для отображения имени
{
    return name;
}
string NOTE::GetPhone()//Функция для отображения телефона
{
    return phone;
}
string NOTE::GetBirthday()//Функция для отображения дня рождения
{
    return birthday;
}
void NOTE::SetName(string n)//Функция для установки имени
{
    name = n;
}
void NOTE::SetPhone(string p)//Функция для установки телефона
{
    phone=p;
}
void NOTE::SetBirthday(string b)//Функция для установки дня рождения
{
    birthday=b;
}
std::ostream& NOTE:: operator<< (std::ostream& out)
{
    out << name;
    return out;
}


#include <iostream>
#include "Contact.h"
#include "Note.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); 
    NOTE Iv("Иван Иванов", "79153670773", "15.02.2001");
}
```

Comment: А что означает «не работает»? Не компилируется? Выбрасывает исключение во время работы? Делает не то, что вы ожидали?

Comment: @Iskander,  вы уже неделю  возитесь с этим `NOTE`, но  недостатки  так и остались. Как вы получите данные константного объекта  зачем столько копирований и т.д.? Я не придираюсь, просто класс примитивный, и на нем  легче тренироваться писать правильно и работать над эффективностью.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну почему не работает. В принципе работает, вот так:

```
Iv << std::cout;
```

Что эквивалентно следующему вызову и вашей сигнатуре `operator<< (std::ostream& out)`

```
Iv.operator<<(std::cout);
```

Если вам нужен синтаксис, при котором `ostream` должен обрабатывать тип `NOTE`, то лучше следующий подход:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, const NOTE& note);

...

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, const NOTE & note)
{
    out << note.name;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, конкретно я затупил конечно